# Setting a tag to a view

Tags: ios, uiview, tags

I am trying to set a tag to a UILabel object so that i can identify it with the tag in a switch case statement

however, when i do this in viewDidLoad :

```
[self.label setTag:1];
 LogInfo(@"label's tag:%d",[self.label tag]);
```

the output in the log is :

```
label's tag:0
```

Why does this happen?

the given label is added to the view programmatically, and does not exist in the interface builder

Comment: maybe you can show the entire initialization of the label

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this will happen if your label is nil.

Comment: Indeed my label was nil! i will accept this answer when stackoverflow allows, thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

before creating label you are trying to set the tag, so it will display nil.